# How to make an int8 python numpy array appear as bool to the user

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, casting

need to store a bool numpy array, but it has to be compatible with an old specification (astropy.io.fits.ImageHDU) which can only store int8 (other types are possible, but int8 is the smallest footprint). The key issue is that the users will want to do

```
mask = np.array((True, False, False, True))
print(np.arange(4, 8)[mask])
[4, 7]
```

which would give a completely different result if mask were to be int

```
[5, 4, 4, 5]
```

Here are two (wrong) implementations to give an idea of what I need

```
import numpy as np
class MyClass(dict):
     @property
     def mask(self):
         return self['mask'].astype(bool)
     @mask.setter
     def mask(self, inmask):
         self['mask'] = inmask.astype(np.int8)
input_mask = np.array((0, 1), dtype=np.int8)
obj = MyClass((('mask', input_mask),))
```

The desired behaviour should have `obj.mask` and `obj['mask']` always synchronised, that is

```
print(obj.mask)
[False, True]
print(obj['mask'])
[0, 1]
obj['mask'][0] = 1
print(obj.mask)
[True, True]
obj.mask[0] = False
print(obj.mask)
[False, True]
print(obj['mask'])
[0, 1]
```

But the implementation fails because `mask` always returns a different instance than `self['mask']`. So, in alternative, I tried

```
import numpy as np
class MyClass(dict):
     @property
     def mask(self):
         try:
             return self._mask
         except AttributeError:
             self._mask = self['mask'].astype(bool)
             return self._mask
     @mask.setter
     def mask(self, inmask):
         self._mask = inmask
         self['mask'] = inmask.astype(np.int8)
input_mask = np.array((0, 1), dtype=np.int8)
obj = MyClass((('mask', input_mask),))
```

This fails because `self._mask` and `self['mask']` go out of sync

```
obj.mask[0] = True
print(obj.mask, ' - ', obj['maks'])
[True True] - [0 1]
```

Comment: Why do you need two arrays (one boolean, one int) in the first place? Note that all boolean arrays in Numpy are int8 (or rather uint8) arrays internally, so what I would do is: (1) store my mask as the int8 array that you require (like `mask = np.array((1, 0, 0, 1), dtype=np.int8)`) and (2) use a *boolean view* of it for masking (like `np.arange(4, 8)[mask.view(dtype=bool)]`). In this way, you would not need to keep two arrays in sync. Also, you wouldn't waste additional memory, as the view does not copy your original int8 data. Or maybe I misunderstood your problem?

Comment: @simon, thank you for replying. I agree with everything you said, but I have external constraints to "waste memory" :-/, to avoid users making the mistake of indexing an array with an int mask

Comment: I see, that makes sense. But you could still maybe work with array views rather than using `astype`? In this way, you could get separate array instances (in the case of bool and int8 even of different type) that still would access the same memory -- which implies that, if the values in one array change, the others change as well. I don't really know your workflow so I can't tell you my opinion where it would be best to implement the change, but maybe think about it.

Comment: Hey @simon , I think you're right, I just need to change the first example to return `self['mask'].view(dtype=bool)` and it does the trick... If you were to be so kind as to write this as answer, I will check again in two days and accept it!

Comment: Good to hear that. Let me see if I find the time :D In any case: glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that specific setup I would directly make use of the fact that the values of a boolean array in Numpy are handled with bytes (i.e. 8-bit values) in the background. I am not totally sure if this is considered to be an implementation detail, but so far, it has worked for me.

This means that we can use Numpy's [`ndarray.view()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) to create two representations of our mask's memory: a boolean representation (for actual masking) and an int8 representation (for specification conformity). As both representations refer to the same memory, this implies that they are already kept in sync, without further work required from our side.

Adjusting your first attempt of an implementation, we could for example write:

```py
import numpy as np

class MyClass(dict):
    
    @property
    def mask(self):
        return self['mask'].view(bool)

    @mask.setter
    def mask(self, inmask):
        assert inmask.dtype in (np.uint8, np.int8, bool)
        self['mask'] = inmask.view(np.int8)
```

Which would then give us the expected behavior:

```py
input_mask = np.array((0, 1), dtype=np.int8)
obj = MyClass((('mask', input_mask),))

# Check behavior
print(obj.mask)
# >>> [False  True]
print(obj['mask'])
# >>> [0 1]
obj['mask'][0] = 1
print(obj.mask)
# >>> [ True  True]
obj.mask[0] = False
print(obj.mask)
# >>> [False  True]
print(obj['mask'])
# >>> [0 1]
```

Note that in this implementation, we actually have *three* representations of the same memory: `inmask` that goes into the setter, `obj['mask']`, and `obj.mask`. If we want to ensure that `inmask` is not altered when changing `obj.mask` or `obj['mask']`(or, likewise, changes to `inmask` don't alter `obj.mask` and `obj['mask']`), we could use `astype()` in the setter, as before.